# Azure Rest API - Policy events

Tags: azure, rest, azure-policy

I am calling the REST API for obtaining Policy events for azure as follows :

URL - "https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/" + subscription_id + "/providers/Microsoft.PolicyInsights/policyEvents/default/queryResults?api-version=2019-10-01"

I opened the API documentation for the same by searching inside the documentation as follows (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/search/?scope=REST&terms=policy%20events) :
[API search for policy events](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TVo2e.png)

But unfortunately I am getting the following error (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/policy-insights/policyevents/listqueryresultsforsubscription):
[Page not found error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mtBOW.png)

Does this mean that they have discontinued providing the Policy events via REST API ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems change the url of [Policy Events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/policy/policyevents) Rest API. This [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/policy/policyevents/listqueryresultsforsubscription) will help to list Query Results For Subscription.

```
POST https://management.azure.com/subscriptions/{subscriptionId}/providers/Microsoft.PolicyInsights/policyEvents/default/queryResults?api-version=2019-10-01
```

Comment: If my reply is helpful, please accept it as answer(click on the mark option beside the reply to toggle it from greyed out to fill in.), see https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work